# SQL: Remove rows if it contains a date in the past

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite Table that contains text but some of the rows of text contain a date (in `MM/DD` or `MM/DD/YY` format) Is there a way to remove all the rows that contain a date that has passed? (for `MM/DD` format I assume 2015 as the year).

I am unsure if SQL can capture a regex and then compare it to the current date

Comment: You should have used one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

Comment: That would make things difficult because the text is user submitted and mm/dd is simple for them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, this requires combining several aspects of SQLite.

```
delete t from t
    where (case when text glob '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]'
                then replace(text, '/', '-')
                when text glob '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]'
                then strftime(date('now'), '%Y') || '-' || substr(text, 1, 2) || '-' || substr(text, 4, 2)
           end) < strftime(date('now'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I keep getting `no such function now`. I switched your strftime functions to  `strftime('%Y', 'now')`  to give current year and `< date('now')` to give current date. But this still returns 0 results. How would I have it display the date it is receiving per row as a test?

Comment: @Bijan . . . Ooops, some MySQL crept in.